# Changing Directory Paths in C#

Tags: c#

Beginner here.

I have a directory structure that has a folder with a random number in the path.

i.e. `c:\folderA\subfolder\dump1\history\var`, `c:\folderA\subfolder\dump22\history\var`

I want the program to read each directory path dynamically. So I split the paths into "partial path" + "fix path". See code.

This is done because \dump* is the unknown and I don't want to hard code it.

The snippet of code below works and is successful but I want to manipulate a portion of the string from the result.

And there lies my problem, I don't know how to change partition string `c:\` to something else. Perhaps a new partition `d:\` or a UNC path `\\someserver\fileshare`

If successfull, it would look like this:

```
D:\folderA\subfolder\dump22\history\var
```

Or

```
\\someserver\fileshare\folderA\subfolder\dump22\history\var
```

This is done so I can write additional code to move contents from \var to another directory etc.

```
{
    static void Main()
    {

        // Grab directory root

        string[] array1 = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\folderA\subfolder\");


        // Display all directory paths
        Console.WriteLine("--- Paths---");
        foreach (string name in array1)
        {
             // Add Partial Path + Fix Path

            String CombinePath = (name + "\\history\\var");
            Console.WriteLine(CombinePath);

            //Results
    //c:\folderA\subfolder\dump1\history\var
            //c:\folderA\subfolder\dump22\history\var

            {

                //pause
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like ["Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

```
CombinePath.Replace(@"C:\", @"D:\");
```

Comment: Thank you all! Great solutions. 

.Replace might be the key. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a search and replace using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary data structure to hold string. If you don't want to define your own string path generation, you could have a look [QueryString](http://querystrings.codeplex.com/)